creating signature for ankr wallet/broadcasttransaction
We are currently developing an application which use ankr services in order to communicate with tron network
now we want to create transaction.
in ankr webservice two steps are required for creating a transaction.
in first step we send data about transaction(sender address, recipient address, amount,...)
in second step we will create a signature for already created transaction,
in this step I use raw_data_hex which ankr returned in first step and my private key to create the signature using following code , but when I send it to ankr, it return SIGERROR, so I need your help for solving this problem.
code I mentioned:
byte[] hexBytes = Convert.FromHexString(privateKeyHex);
var privateKeyKey = new ECKey(hexBytes ,true);
var dataHash = Convert.FromHexString(hexTransactionData).ToSHA256Hash();
var res = privateKeyKey.Sign(dataHash);
return res.ToDER().ToHex();

second step request to ankr api:
var payload = new
{
    signature = new string[] { signature },
    txID = firstStepResponse["txID"],
    raw_data = firstStepResponse["raw_data"]
};

var result = await SendRequest("https://rpc.ankr.com/http/tron/wallet/broadcasttransaction", payload);

